# Why is momentum not conserved in this particle interaction?

Tags: particle-physics, momentum, conservation-laws

In this particle equation.

$$\Lambda^0 \rightarrow n$$

I thought it would be possible to conserve momentum as the neutron could carry on in a straight line and adjust its speed accordingly so the momentum of the $\Lambda$ particle is equal to the momentum of the Neutron.

But I have been told it is not possible as momentum is not conserved, so what is the fault in my reasoning?

Comment: Momentum is conserved since the interaction is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can't simultaneously conserve energy and momentum.

Let's do everything in the rest frame of the $\Lambda^0$ for convenience. This means that $E_\Lambda=m_\Lambda$ and $\mathbf{p}_\Lambda=\mathbf{0}$. But after the reaction, you have only a single neutron, which must therefore possess both all of the energy of the original $\Lambda^0$ *and* and all of the momentum. So you must have a neutron with $E_n=m_\Lambda$ and $\mathbf{p}_n=\mathbf{0}$.

Suppose that you imposed conservation of energy, requiring that $E_n=m_\Lambda$. But $E_n=\sqrt{m_n^2+\mathbf{p_n}^2}$ and $m_n<m_\Lambda$, so you must have $\mathbf{p_n}\neq\mathbf{0}$ to conserve energy, which violates conservation of momentum (since $\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{0}$ in this frame before the reaction).

Suppose instead that you imposed conservation of momentum, requiring that $\mathbf{p}_n=\mathbf{0}$. Then the neutron would have to be at rest, meaning that $E_n=m_n$. But $m_n<m_\Lambda$, so $E_n<E_\Lambda$, which violates conservation of energy.

Since both conservation of energy and conservation of momentum must be obeyed in any valid reaction, this reaction is impossible.

Comment: I am not sure how you got to this statement =root(2+2)

Comment: @daniel Special relativity energy/mass/momentum relationship. It's a basic relationship which applies routinely to particle reactions.

Answer (score 1):

According to special relativity, the mass of a closed system is defined by
$$mc^2=\sqrt{E^2-p^2c^2},$$
where $E=\sum_i E_i$, and $p=|\sum_i \vec{p_i} |$. The sums are over all the particles in the system. Each energy $E_i$ is $K_i+m_ic^2$, where $K_i$ is the kinetic of the particle. The kinetic energy and momentum of each particle are relative to a specific reference frame, and the particle mass, $m_i$ is the rest mass.

The remarkable thing about the first equation/statement is that mc^2 is *Lorentz invariant*, the it, it is the same value for all inertial reference frame measurements. As a side note, the $m$ value is **not** necessarily the sum of the particle masses.

In your reaction, we can first choose the rest frame of the $\Lambda_0$. In this frame, we have a single particle at rest, $K=0$ and $\vec{p}=0$.
$$mc^2=\sqrt{m_{\Lambda}^2c^4-0}=m_{\Lambda}c^2$$

After the reaction we would have a single neutron. Lorentz invariance allows us to calculate $mc^2$ of the system in any reference frame. We can now choose the neutron rest frame:
$$mc^2=\sqrt{(0+m_n c^2)^2+0}=m_nc^2$$

This tells us that unless the mass of the $\Lambda_0$ and the neutron are the same, the reaction cannot happen within the constraints of energy and momentum conservation.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the center of mass of the $Λ$ it has a mass of $1115.6MeV/c^2$. The neutron has a mass of $939.6.6MeV/c^2$ almost $200 MeV/c^2$ excess. With the neutron shooting off as you would like, suddenly before, momentum is zero, and after  the neutron will have to have this excess energy as kinetic energy, and momentum will not be conserved , because there is nothing to recoil against to balance the momentum.

In addition, the [$Λ$ is a baryon](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/baryon.html#c1) composed out of  an up quark a down quark and and s quark. It is the [s quark that decays](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html#c2) with the weak interaction , and it goes into an up quark and a virtual $W^-$ which decays into an electron and an electon antineutrino ( to conserve lepton number).

[image: s decay]

The hadron now has no s but an up quark and thus it has to be a proton. Charge conservation is assured by the electron.

So not only the kinematics you envisage are not correct, but also the actual decay cannot happen [within the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics.